# What does it mean when the Xenomorph's hands are described as bio-mechanical?

Tags: alien-franchise

In the "Aliens" novelisation, the Xenomorph's hands are described as *bio-mechanical*. My understanding is that they are not a technological species, is the description an inconsistency or is it meant to mean they look bio-mechanical? Am I wrong in thinking they're not technologically advanced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On its surface, it's a meaningless word to apply. [Biomechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomechanics) is simply the science of biological movement and how it operates. However, in the case of the Xenomorph, it refers to the original inspiration, H.R. Giger's book, *[Biomechanics](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/310772.Biomechanics)*, which features biological creatures melded with machines. Furthermore, it conjures up an imagery of a creature that is optimized, much as a machine might be, stripped down to its bare essentials, nothing wasted.

As described in *[Alien: Evolution](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Evolution)*:

> [Giger's] design for the creature was heavily influenced by an aesthetic he had created and termed *biomechanical*, a fusion of the organic and the mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

Xenomorphs were pure biological in nature.

But, according to AvP canon, Livermore Evanston created Xenoborgs in his plan to control the galaxy.

"The main cybernetic changes to the xenomorphs were that they could be radio controlled and the addition of armour and weapons. The controlling equipment was housed in their heads, and allowed someone to control them from a distance via a control panel, although the range of this control is unknown."

The bio-mechanical hands were just a start-up part of his experiments.

References:

[Hunter’s Planet](http://www.avpgalaxy.net/literature/reviews/avp-hunters-planet/)

[Livermore Evanston](http://hu.alienspredatoraliens-versus-predator.wikia.com/wiki/Livermore_Evanston)

Try to find and read the novel itself, it's quite interesting overall.